# does prctl(pr_set_dumpable, 1) has visible side effects?

Tags: linux, process

I used `prctl(pr_set_dumpable, 1)` after `setuid()` call to have the coredumps generation enabled.
I found that use of `prctl(pr_set_dumpable, 1)` also changes the owner:group of all the files at `/proc/(pid)` location, is this a side affect or expected?

Answer (score 3):

For the record, I just tripped over this myself trying to turn coredumps *off*, and I'm not using `setuid`.  When I ran this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char ls_cmd[64];
  snprintf(ls_cmd, sizeof(ls_cmd), "/bin/ls -ld /proc/%d/fd", getpid());

  system(ls_cmd);

  if (0 > prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 0)) {
    perror("can't prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE)");
    return 1;
  }

  system(ls_cmd);

  return 0;
}
```

I got this result (redacted):

```
$ ./prctl-and-proc
dr-x------ 2 myuname mygroup 0 Feb  2 17:08 /proc/23999/fd
dr-x------ 2 root root 0 Feb  2 17:08 /proc/23999/fd
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is done by dumpable.  You can see why by looking at

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/fs/proc/base.c?id=refs/tags/v3.14

and search for 'dumpable'.  The inode uids are first set to GLOBAL_ROOT_UID, then set to the owner uid only if the task is dumpable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is the `prctl` and not the `setuid` syscall which changes ownership of `/proc/self/`? I'm guessing that `setuid` should change it....

Comment: yeah I am sure, setuid is not able to change /proc/self ownership while using prctl(pr_set_dumpavlr, 1) changes it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `setuid` (or `seteuid` & other similar syscalls) is changing it. Otherwise, all `/proc/` directories would belong to root (since all processes have `init` as their ancestor, but `prctl` is almost never used), and they don't.

Comment: that's what i used to think! but prctl(pr_set_dumpavlr, 1) changes the owner:groups accordingly in the /proc/self/ folder only.

Answer (score 0):

man proc
Resetting the "dumpable" attribute to 1 reverts the ownership of the /proc/[pid]/* files to the process's real UID and real GID.